# php json error fetching?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, oop

I am making server side android app 
but my php code are not working correctly .. it show my else part only..  You are not authorized... PLease help me 
here is my php code -

```
class DbFoodFunctions {

    private $conn;
    private function openDB() {

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "blood";
        $this -> conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($this -> conn -> connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn -> connect_error);
        }

    }

    private function closeDB() {
        $this -> conn -> close();
    }


    public function searchFood($money)
    {
        $this -> openDB();
        $stmt = $this -> conn -> prepare("Select * from FOOD where amount >= ?"); //  SELECT distinct(NAME) FROM XZY WHERE Amount= ?
        $stmt -> bind_param("i", $money);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $result = $stmt -> get_result();
        $numrows = $result -> num_rows;
        $this -> closeDB();
        $res = array();
        $res['numrows'] = $numrows;
        while ($myrow = $result -> fetch_object()) {
            $res[] = $myrow;

        }
        return $res;
    }


}
?>

index.php

<?php

require_once 'db/db.php';

$dbObj = new DbFoodFunctions();
$action = '';
$result = array();

if ($action == 'searchFood') {
    $money = '';
        if (isset($_REQUEST['money'])) {
            $money = trim($_REQUEST['money']);
        }
        $res = $dbObj -> searchFood($money);
        $result['success'] = 1;
        $result['data'] = $res;
        echo json_encode($result);
}else {
    $result['error'] = 1;
    $result['message'] = "You are not authorized";  // i am getting this msg only
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: $action is not 'searchFood'

Comment: in other words, you need to change this line: `$action = '';` so $action is something, not just an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You set the $action variable to an empty string two lines before checking its value, which is why your code is executing the else block.  The stuff in the 'If' block only gets executed if the corresponding expression evaluates to true.